# Placing .profile under BOOT-INF/classes not working

Tags: spring-boot, cloud-foundry

i am using spring boot 1.5.4 try to generate the jar and deploying in PCF(Cloud foundry ) . I place the .profile under BOOT-INF/classes , it is not executing in PCF can some one can help me regarding this .

Thanks

Comment: Is there any working gradle example ? how to move to .profile to the root of the jar

Answer (score 0):

The `.profile` file must be in the root of your JAR and not under `BOOT-INF/classes`.

If you are using the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` your JAR is repackaged and the `.profile` will be moved to `BOOT-INF/classes` where it is not recognized by *Cloud Foundry*.
You can check the location of the `.profile` location for example via `$ vi your.jar`.

If you `cf ssh ...` into your app you should find the `.profile` directly in the app folder.

If you are using `spring-boot-maven-plugin` I would recommend putting the `.profile` in the root of your project and add another build plugin to update the JAR after repackaging, make sure it is below the `spring-boot-maven-plugin`.

```
            <plugin>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>update build artifacts</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <executable>jar</executable>
                        <commandlineArgs>-uvf target/your.jar .profile</commandlineArgs>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```